# Use Lambda Comparator with PriorityQueue

Tags: c#, .net

Documentation only shows deriving from IComparer and then specifying the derived class as the comparator in the constructor of PriorityQueue, but with multiple priority queues, it creates too many extra classes.

Is it possible to just use Lambda comparator with PriorityQueue class in C#?

Comment: You can easily create an `IComparer<T>` implementation which takes a lambda

Comment: I was hoping for something like what Java has, where you specify lambda expression directly in the PriorityQueue's constructor. Keeps code very clean

Comment: IIRC, you can easily create a comparer from lambda, e.g. `Comparer<int>.Create((a, b) => a.CompareTo(b))`.

Comment: Keeping comparer construction separate from the classes that use them is arguably even cleaner. :P Besides, it's a one-liner.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

While the other answer is good, the quick one-liner solution as mentioned in comments by other users is:

```
//Descending Sort, Integer
var queue = new PriorityQueue<int, int>(Comparer<int>.Create((x, y) => y - x));

//Ascending Sort, Object
var queue = new PriorityQueue<ObjectA, ObjectB>(Comparer<ObjectB>.Create((x, y) => x.Something.CompareTo(y.Something));
```

Note that second element i.e. priority, can either be an object or primitive data type.

Comment: I am trying to do the same .
var pq = new PriorityQueue<Pair, int>(Comparer<Pair>.Create((x, y) => y.freq.CompareTo(x.freq)));

Here is my pair class
public class Pair
{
    public int freq;
    public int coolTime;
    public Pair()
    {

    }
    public Pair(int freq, int coolTime)
    {
        this.freq = freq;
        this.coolTime = coolTime;
    }

}
I am still getting this error. I am not sure where is my mistake.
 cannot convert comparer<pair> to icomparer<int>

Answer (score 1):

A fairly standard helper class would be something like this:

```
    public class KeyComparer<T, TKey> : IComparer<T> 
    {
        private readonly Func<T, TKey> selector;
        private IComparer<TKey> comparer;
        public KeyComparer(Func<T, TKey> selector) : this(selector, Comparer<TKey>.Default){}
        public KeyComparer(Func<T, TKey> selector, IComparer<TKey> comparer) => (this.selector, this.comparer) = (selector, comparer);
        public int Compare(T x, T y) => comparer.Compare(selector(x), selector(y));
    }
```

You can create extension methods or static factory methods to help avoid needing to create the comparers explicitly.

Comment: For maximal flexibility this should probably not require that `TKey` is `IComparable` but instead take an `IComparer<TKey>` of its own (using `Comparer<TKey>.Default` as a fallback). That said, I'm not sure this class adds a lot as opposed to just using `Comparer` with a slightly more complicated expression, since it's effectively just chaining two functions.

Comment: This isn't massively different to `Comparer<Thing>.Create((x, y) => x.Something.CompareTo(y.Something))`?